# Is MultiPart file deprecated in Spring 3.?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, multipartform-data, spring-3

Is the multipart deprecated in Spring Boot new version 3.x.x
I am only getting MultiPartProperties, MultiPartName, MultiPartAutoConfiguration.
Which one should I use for uploading files?

I am currently using Spring Boot version 3.2.0

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
```

from this dependency

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

It is present and not deprecated in `3.2.0`

https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-uploading-files/blob/main/complete/src/main/java/com/example/uploadingfiles/FileUploadController.java

https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/